# How do I fix this java home error (trying to download visual studio)?

Tags: java, visual-studio

ERROR: export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.jdk/Contents/Homefor f in $HOME/.bash_profile.d/*.bash

This is the error I received. How can I fix this in the terminal? Thank you!

Full error below:

==> Next steps:

- Run `brew help` to get started
- Further documentation:
  https://docs.brew.sh
  ++ grep -c 'eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)' /Users/neerav/.bash_profile

- '[' 0 -eq 0 ']'
- [[ -f /opt/homebrew/bin/brew ]]
- source /Users/neerav/.bash_profile
  ++ export M2_HOME=/Applications/apache-maven-3.8.2
  ++ M2_HOME=/Applications/apache-maven-3.8.2
  ++ export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin:/Applications/apache-maven-3.8.2/bin:/Applications/apache-maven-3.8.2/bin:/Applications/apache-maven-3.8.2/bin
  ++ PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin:/Applications/apache-maven-3.8.2/bin:/Applications/apache-maven-3.8.2/bin:/Applications/apache-maven-3.8.2/bin
  ++ export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.jdk/Contents/Homefor f in /Users/neerav/.bash_profile.d/aliases.bash /Users/neerav/.bash_profile.d/git_branch_ps1.bash /Users/neerav/.bash_profile.d/ls_colors.bash /Users/neerav/.bash_profile.d/silence_deprecation_warning.bash
  ++ JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.jdk/Contents/Homefor
  /Users/neerav/.bash_profile: line 4: export: `/Users/neerav/.bash_profile.d/aliases.bash': not a valid identifier /Users/neerav/.bash_profile: line 4: export:` /Users/neerav/.bash_profile.d/git_branch_ps1.bash': not a valid identifier
  /Users/neerav/.bash_profile: line 4: export: `/Users/neerav/.bash_profile.d/ls_colors.bash': not a valid identifier /Users/neerav/.bash_profile: line 4: export:` /Users/neerav/.bash_profile.d/silence_deprecation_warning.bash': not a valid identifier
- catch 1 'export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.jdk/Contents/Homefor f in $HOME/.bash_profile.d/*.bash'
- set +xv

ERROR: export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.jdk/Contents/Homefor f in $HOME/.bash_profile.d/*.bash
There was an error setting up your code editor.
Please find the lfz-code.log file on your Desktop.
Send the file to an instructor in a chat message so they can help.